# Imagick & PHP: Colorize an image without loss of contrast

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I have a PHP script that colorizes an image uploaded by the user by using ImageMagick.
The script works fine and is simple but the result is washed out.

I added a levels adjustment and was able to get some improved contrast but Imagick::colorizeImage() basically kills all the black in the image and it ain't coming back.

```
$image = new Imagick("./image.jpg");
//Make Greyscale
$image->modulateImage(90, 0, 100);
//Sharpen and deepen the contrast
$image->levelImage(0 , 0.4, 50535);
// Colorize         
$color   = new ImagickPixel("rgba(80, 175, 210, 1)");
$opacity = new ImagickPixel("rgba(0, 0, 0, 80)");
$image->colorizeImage ( $color , $opacity );
```

So I inverted the image using negateImage(), applied colorizeImage() and then inverted it back. Now I have the black and the image looks better, but now all the white is washed out.

```
$image = new Imagick("./image.jpg");
//Make Greyscale
$image->modulateImage(90, 0, 100);
//Sharpen and deepen the contrast
$image->levelImage(0 , 0.4, 50535);
$image->negateImage(true);
// Colorize         
$color   = new ImagickPixel("rgba(80, 175, 210, 1)");
$opacity = new ImagickPixel("rgba(0, 0, 0, 80)");
$image->colorizeImage ( $color , $opacity );
$image->negateImage(false);
```

I want to keep all the blacks and all the whites and colorize everything else. Is this possible?

Comment: no expert with that library, but a workaround would be to colorize the image (a copy) and then replace every pixel that is black or white in the original with black or white in the colorized image.

Comment: That could work. If you do that you don't get the gradation and it might look a bit rough. I also thought of trying to apply a black alpha mask of the greyscale image to the postive coloriized version, but I have not found a function or procedure that provides photoshop-like alpha masking/selection.

Comment: Just use the tintImage method?